The method 'setTrackingSource' was not found in "_paq" variable
Am getting the below error for the website am trying to setup the Free Version Piwik Pro. The website is made on Wordpress and am currently using the plugin to add the container address and siteID. Am not sure what am doing wrong here. Can someone shed some guidiance what I might be missing apart from only adding the plugin to the website? https://www.ixcheldayspa.com/
The method 'setTrackingSource' was not found in "_paq" variable.  Please have a look at the Piwik tracker documentation: https://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/tracking-javascript
ak @ analytics.js:22Understand this error

Uncaught TypeError: The method 'setTrackingSource' was not found in "_paq" variable.  Please have a look at the Piwik tracker documentation: https://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/tracking-javascript
    at af (analytics.js:23:416)
    at ad (analytics.js:74:994)
    at Object.addTracker (analytics.js:76:837)
    at analytics.js:79:508
    at analytics.js:80:548Understand this error

Matomo javascript tracker or Piwik PRO javascript tracker was already initiated on this page. Please check the tracker setup. Matomo conflict can be resolved using these instructions: https://help.piwik.pro/support/questions/can-i-use-piwik-pro-and-matomo-at-the-same-time/.

I tried adding the JS code to the website instead of the plugin and I get the same error code.
